# When a file changes, I'd like to modify one or more different files

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

I've been scouring the web for hours looking for an approach to solving this problem, and I just can't find one. Hopefully someone can fast-track me. I'd like to cause the following behaviour:

When running `ember s` and a file of a certain extension is changed, I'd like to analyze the contents of that file and write to several other files in the same directory.

To give a specific example, let's assume I have a file called `app/dashboard/dashboard.ember`. `dashboard.ember` consists of 3 concatenated files: `app/dashboard/controller.js`, `.../route.js`, and `.../template.hbs` with a reasonable delimiter between the files. When `dashboard.ember` is saved, I'd like to call a function (inside an addon, I assume) that reads the file, splits it at the delimiter and writes the corresponding splitted files. `ember-cli` should then pick up the changed source (`.js`, `.hbs`, etc.) files that it knows how to handle, ignoring the `.ember` file.

I could write this as a standalone application, of course, but I feel like it *should* be integrated with the `ember-cli` build environment, but I can't figure out what concoction of hooks and tools I should use to achieve this.

Comment: What you need is a broccoli plugin that reads `*.ember` and outputs the wanted files.

Comment: Is there a good filter example? All the ones I looked at use setupPreprocessorRegistry(), but that would make changes in the build tree, not amongst the source files. I still need to keep the original `route.js`, `template.hbs`, etc. in the source alongside my `dashboard.ember`. preBuild() makes the most sense, but it doesn't provide the set of changed files. I'd have to scan the whole source tree myself each time, writing all the corresponding files, not just the ones that changed. Would `ember s` even notice the new changes (because it has already checked for changes) before building?

Comment: What do you mean you keep the "original files in the source"? Isn't `.ember` the original one?

Comment: Yes, you're right; I was unclear (and only had 600 characters). I want to keep the `.ember` and modify the `route.js`, `template.hbs`, `controller.js` etc., keeping them in the source tree. Ember should build off the latter files; I want to use the former for convenience when editing so I don't have 15 tabs open at once, many of them with the same name.